# C++ Read from a file and ignore both whitespace and \t

Tags: c++

When I have a file like this:

```
1 Boston and Chicago
```

OR

```
1   Boston and Chicago
```

the code that I have:

```
std::string line 
std::string name 
int num; 
getline(filename, line);
```

How to store the number 1 in num variable, and “Boston and Chicago” string in name variable, in both cases? The first case with just ONE whitespace, and the other case with \t space.

Comment: please do not tag spam, this is not a C question

Comment: Have a look at [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream).

Comment: [A tutorial on basic IO using C++](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_basic_input_output.htm) might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

you need to tokenize the line.  Now if it is always going to be a number, followed by some white-space (tab is a type of white-space) and then a string, you can do something like this:

```
    std::string::size_t   nloc = std::string::npos;

    if(std::string::npos != (nloc = line.find_first_of(" \t")))
    {
         std::string first = line.substr(0, nloc);

         std::string second = line.substr(nloc+1, line.length() - nloc);

         // perform other processing of first and second here
     }
```

the function `find_first_of` is described in [full here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_first_of/).  Please note that with the above you may need to do additional processing (such as removing leading or trailing white space, but with `find_first_of` and `find_first_not_of` functions this is trivial).

After doing this, you can then use `atoi` to convert the first string to an integer (although I would do validation to make sure that the first string contains only digits prior to making a conversion).